# Radeon R9 with motherboard HDMI

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, hdmi, amd-radeon

I currently have 2 screens, one with HDMI and one with VGA connection. 
My desktop has an AMD Radeon R9 Fury series video card in it, my HDMI screen is attached directly to it. Now I want to connect my second monitor as well to my PC. So i bought a VGA to HDMI converter and I tried plugging the screen in on my motherboard's HDMI input. The screen is not recognized and just does not work.

If i plug out my main screen from my graphics card and plug it directly in the motherboard socket, it works.
What is going on?

Comment: In most cases the onboard GPU is disabled automatically when a video card is installed. Check your BIOS settings, in many computers you can set it to stay enabled, but not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no connection between the motherboard HDMI socket and your graphics card so it does not work.

The motherboard HDMI socket connects to the iGPU that would be built into your processor. If you have a dedicated card (the R9) then the iGPU will have been disabled.

You have to use whatever ports are available on the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your second screen to another output of your Radeon R9, there is no need to mix the motherboard in the configuration.

Comment: the radeon only has 1 HDMI port and no VGA one. I don't have any other ways to connect it to the gpu

Comment: Why don't you then connect directly VGA on Radeon to VGA on the monitor? All monitors have VGA port.

Comment: the radeon does not have VGA ?